# java thread System.in how can i "wait for console commands"

Tags: java, console, command, serversocket

Let's say I got System.in

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

result = br.readLine();
                while (!result.isEmpty()) {
                    if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                        userStr="exit";
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
                        userStr="list";
                    } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("kill")) {
                        userStr="kill";
                    } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
                        userStr="help";
}
```

and

```
ServerSocket socketListener = new ServerSocket(port);
while (true) {
                Socket client = socketListener.accept();
                new ServerThread(client,userStr); //pass userStr to Thread               
            }
```

i don't understand how can i "wait for console commands" and pass them to active Thread. I need to accept() clients, pass them to thread. If I entered a command into the server console like for example; "kill Username"(disconnect user) or "list"(list of Usernames)
my server should pass commands to threads.

p/s I need manage server, manage implemented by entering the console commands.

Comment: Have a look at the Queue implementations in [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Comment: I still don't understand the question you have. The title is not telling me anything and although I understand what you want to do, I still don't understand what you wanted to ask. What's your problem with solving this job? Obviously you know about threading, so "wait for console commands" should not be a problem?

Comment: I tried to update the question, if I did a mistake, feel free to update the question again. And for future problems you should really try to put some effort into your questions. Keep in mind that we do no get paid to answer your questions. This is completely voluntary, and people take time out of their busy schedule to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/review/

Comment: read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and reformat your question accordingly

Comment: @Fuji i understand that i take you time or someone else, sry for that.Question is, i don't understand how can i "wait for console commands"

Comment: @linski i reformat my question

Comment: No worries. We are here to help, but making sure that you spend more time on your questions will make it much easier for us to help you. :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As easy solution you can block you thread untill it will recieve a task to execute :

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    AtomicReference<String> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<String>(null);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            String command = atomicReference.getAndSet(null);
            if (command != null) {
                //do staff with command
            }
        }
    }

    public void executeCommand(String command) {
        atomicReference.set(command);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
ServerSocket socketListener = new ServerSocket(port);
Task task = new Task();
new Thread(task).start();

while (true) {
            Socket client = socketListener.accept();
            task.executeCommand(userCommand);
        }
```

But if you need more complex solution I can advice you to read about Java Concurrency package:

[Avesome book about that](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0321349601/?tag=hydra0b-21&hvadid=9550950909&ref=asc_df_0321349601)

[Good article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things4/index.html)